# Hana Timestamp Query - Age of Tracefile

Tags: sql, timestamp, hana

I have been playing around with SAP's Hana Database. I found an instance of  Hana (30 day trial version) deployed on cloudshare.net. I have been firing SQL statements on `hdbsql`, a command line tool (similar to SQL*plus in oracle).

I need help with one specific query written to calculate the age of tracefiles.

***Query:***

```
Select * from M_TRACEFILES
```

The query returns trace files and their associated information. I am interested in one column "FILE_MTIME" which is the time and date when the file was created. Its datatype is "timestamp" which in HANA has the following format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm:ss.fff7' where `fff` is fractional seconds up to 7 digits. Example: `2010-01-11 17:38:48.8020025`.

To find the age of the tracefile I need:

**"Current_Local_Timestamp_On_Node - Tracefile_Timestamp".**

Following is the way to query current timestamp on a HANA node:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP "current timestamp" FROM DUMMY;
```

Output:

```
 current timestamp
 2010-01-11 17:38:48.802
```

How do I do this in one query so that I can get all the tracefile related info and its age in query result.

In HANA are there any timestamp operations like Oracle's date operation where you can say "sysdate - somedate".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see here for [DateTime functions of HANA](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/9f228975191014baed94f1b69693ae/content.htm)

you want probably something like

```
SELECT *, SECONDS_BETWEEN(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, FILE_MTIME) FROM M_TRACEFILES
```

(I can't test this right now, but you get the idea)

Here is the [whole sql guide of HANA](http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_SQL_Reference_en.pdf)

Comment: Hi 203 thanks for your reply. I tested the query on the hana environment. It worked. Here is the Query i fired:                                          hdbsql HDB=> Select FILE_NAME , SECONDS_BETWEEN(FILE_MTIME , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS Trace_File_Age from M_TRACEFILES , DUMMY

Comment: @mohan you can even leave out `, DUMMY`. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is not fetched from there, it is a datetime function itself. You just need the dummy if you do not select from another table.